# Add ts-prune to lint-staged

Tags: package.json, husky, dead-code, lint-staged

I'd like to run `ts-prune` in order to detect dead code on the files staged for commit using `lint-staged`.

I've tried the following:

```
"find-deadcode": "ts-prune -e",
...
```

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
    "npm run find-deadcode",
    "eslint --fix"
  ]
}
```

However it lists all files with dead code instead of only the ones that are going to be commmited.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lint-staged` works by passing the list of staged files to the specified commands. Since `ts-prune` doesn't take a list of files as an argument it doesn't work out-of-the-box with `lint-staged`.

An alternative to @James's answer if you want to use `lint-staged` is to wrap `ts-prune` in a script that takes the file list supplied by `lint-staged` and filters the output using it.

`tools/ts-prune-included.sh`

```js
const {exec} = require('child_process');

const includedFiles = process.argv
  .slice(2)
  .map(path => path.replace(process.cwd() + '/', ''));

exec('npx ts-prune', (_, stdout) => {
  const result = stdout
    .split('\n')
    .filter(line => includedFiles.some(file => line.startsWith(file)))
    .join('\n');

    console.log(result);
    process.exit(result ? 1 : 0)
})
```

And you'd use it in the `lint-staged` config like so:

```json
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
    "node tools/ts-prune-included.js",
    "eslint --fix"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is much better, so I've retracted mine.